# What does Spartan feature set mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm stuck with understanding the following sentence from *Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14*

> Programmers familiar with other threading APIs are sometimes surprised
>   at the comparatively Spartan feature set that C++ offers, but that's
>   because a great deal of C++'s support for concurrency is in the form
>   of constraints on compiler writers.

I know Sparta is an ancient Greek city, but what is Spartan feature set?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Are you sure [spartan](https://www.google.com/search?q=spartan+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xlLHWOPqI-yw8weIlaqYCA) was capitalized?

Comment: @Cascabel Yeah, I just follow the book's style.

Comment: What does your dictionary say about "Spartan"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a *Spartan feature* but a *Spartan feature set*, i.e., a Spartan set of features. The Spartans were known for their refusal to indulge in excess or luxury, so this phrase means having the bare minimum set of features. Here's an example from [fiction](https://books.google.com/books?id=ks-3BQAAQBAJ&pg=PT137&dq=%22spartan%20living%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ5_vX99TSAhWD4SYKHfASCL04FBDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22spartan%20living%22&f=false):

> Bright sunlight streamed into the **spartan** living room from which almost every object vaguely nonutilitarian had been banished.

The *OED* reports that the word *Spartan* as a noun for an inhabitant of the city dates from 1425, and as a simple attributive from 1582. We owe the first attributive of character to Milton's [*Aeropagitica*](https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ENGL402-Milton-Aeropagitica.pdf) (1644), his polemic against pre-publication licensing and censorship. Milton notes that the Lycurgus, the ruler of Sparta whose edicts brought about the city's militaristic austerity, brought the musician Thales of Crete to Sparta to

> to prepare and mollifie the **Spartan** surlinesse with his
>   smooth songs and odes....

Comment: Downvoted for a) answering a question that merely required the use of a dictionary, and then b) not even using dictionary research in your answer.

Comment: @AndyT Your name has been reported with favor in dispatches to the CPVPV. I have elsewhere expressed my attitude toward the risible notion that ELU is an academic aerie so lofty as to preclude such answers, so I won't belabor that here. I must note, however, my joy at finding a downvoter who has the common courtesy to explain his downvote. Also a comment upvote for deprecating both the mereness and the absence of "dictionary research". Well, played!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that explanation of downvotes is courteous. With respect to that, my downvote would be removed if a dictionary reference were edited in. And sorry for not coming up with any amusing sarcasm in this comment - I feel like I'm letting the team down.

Comment: @AndyT A magnanimous offer, but adding the reference wouldn't address the a) part of your first comment, which has the imprimatur of the site, no matter my personal tastes. No need to compromise on that. No need either for an amusing retort: at this point your team is so far ahead, that they've stopped keeping score. I did wonder how long *spartan* has had this meaning in English, so I hied myself to the *OED*.